# Checking if an object is of a private class

Tags: powershell

I'd like to check if an object is of type of a private class.

Usually, I check for types using the `-is` keyword, but this does not seems to work using private class:

```
$myObject -is [MyAssembly.MyPrivateClass]
```

Outputs :

> Type [MyAssembly.MyPrivateClass] cannot be found

How to make it works with private classes ?

As a workaround, I can write this:

```
$myObject.GetType().FullName -eq "MyAssembly.MyPrivateClass"
```

But it's quite less readable.

Comment: How did you instantiate the `$myObject` instance?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: the $myobject class is populated with a 3rd party command. Actually, the class have a base type, which is public

Comment: I'm asking because non-nested classes can't be private - they're either public, or internal (default) - and you can't instantiate and expose a private class outside of its parent.

Comment: Simply add a boolean method to the exposed class that does the check.

Comment: I think you are going to have to use your workaround. You can add a comment to increase comprehensibility. Or you could wrap the type checking code into a function, for example `Compare-Type`.